# Read slf4j property values using java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

how to read below slf4j property values using java class

```
<Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%X{id}] Management: [%X{apiName}] trace_id=%X{trace_id} [%X{user}] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
```

I tried using the below but its won't work

```
  public String sample(){
        String val = ThreadContext.get("trace_id");
        System.out.println("val" + val);
        return "sample";
    }
```

what i need is print trace_id using system out

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking about log4j or slf4j? Edit the question to clarify.